# IF-THEN-ELSE statements in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm looking to write a postgresql query to do the following :

```
if(field1 > 0,  field2 / field1 , 0)
```

I've tried this query, but it's not working

```
if (field1 > 0)
then return field2 / field1 as field3
else return 0 as field3
```

thank youu

Comment: look at "conditional expressions" (CASE) http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html

Answer (score 261, accepted):

As stated in PostgreSQL docs [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-conditional.html):

> The SQL CASE expression is a generic conditional expression, similar to if/else statements in other programming languages.

Code snippet specifically answering your question:

```
SELECT field1, field2,
  CASE
    WHEN field1>0 THEN field2/field1
    ELSE 0
  END 
  AS field3
FROM test
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, wasn't there any solution using if-then-else statement? The question asked for an if-then-else but the answer is a switch-case statement.

Comment: Hi Abel, the question asked for the solution to a specific problem. The answer addresses that specific problem. Within `SELECT` statements the conditionals you can use, of which one is `CASE`, are documented [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-conditional.html).

Comment: In that case, it will be more clear if you add in the answer the reason why is more difficult or why you can't achieve this using if-then the statement.

Comment: @MaximilianoBecerra Done. Please take a look. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: The `AS` instruction is not necessary. You can do this `END field3`

Comment: @JosephVictorZammit - I've been looking for [that documentation on **select statement conditionals**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html) for a couple days, but all I'd been getting was docs on conditionals _inside_ functions.  I guess I didn't have the right magic google incantation until now, and your earlier comment was golden!  Thank you!

Answer (score 37):

```
case when field1>0 then field2/field1 else 0 end as field3
```

Answer (score 5):

In general, an alternative to `case when ...` is `coalesce(nullif(x,bad_value),y)` (that cannot be used in OP's case). For example,

```
select coalesce(nullif(y,''),x), coalesce(nullif(x,''),y), *
from (     (select 'abc' as x, '' as y)
 union all (select 'def' as x, 'ghi' as y)
 union all (select '' as x, 'jkl' as y)
 union all (select null as x, 'mno' as y)
 union all (select 'pqr' as x, null as y)
) q
```

gives:

```
 coalesce | coalesce |  x  |  y  
----------+----------+-----+-----
 abc      | abc      | abc | 
 ghi      | def      | def | ghi
 jkl      | jkl      |     | jkl
 mno      | mno      |     | mno
 pqr      | pqr      | pqr | 
(5 rows)
```

Comment: sometimes i don't want the pageantry of `case when` and this fits the bill