# Variable date format query

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, psql

I'm trying to convert strings extracted from a PostgreSQL table (using an indexed aggregated array) into correctly formatted dates to query. My problem is that my date formats vary, consisting of YYYY, Mon YYYY, and DD Mon YYYY. My plan is to create date ranges to encompass all possible time represented by ambiguous dates. For example, "2000" would be converted to "01 Jan 2000" and "31 Dec 2000" and tested against a custom input date range. Similarly, "Feb 2014" will be changed to "01 Feb 2014" and "28 Feb 2014". (Note - I'm currently unable to think of a way to account for leap years)

The method I'm currently working with involves simple string concatenation. However, I need to be able to distinguish string length (which would indicate date format), and I'm struggling to incorporate a conditional expression into my query. Here's what I've got at the moment:

```
SELECT a.accession, string_agg(b.value, ' | ') AS bvalue_list, c.name, d.description, string_agg(e.value, ' | ') AS evalue_list, f.seqlen, f.residues 
FROM dbxref a INNER JOIN dbxrefprop b ON a.dbxref_id = b.dbxref_id
INNER JOIN biomaterial d ON b.dbxref_id = d.dbxref_id
INNER JOIN feature f ON d.dbxref_id = f.dbxref_id
INNER JOIN biomaterialprop e ON d.biomaterial_id = e.biomaterial_id
INNER JOIN contact c ON d.biosourceprovider_id = c.contact_id
GROUP BY a.accession, c.name, d.description, f.seqlen, f.residues
HAVING ((array_agg(b.value))[5] = 'source018' OR (array_agg(b.value))[5] = 'source015')
AND to_date('04 Jan ' || (array_agg(e.value))[3], 'DD Mon YYYY') BETWEEN '01 Jan 1999' AND '31 Jan 2000';
```

I apologize for the crazy query statement. I wanted to show the statement in its entirety because of its quirks (where information is processed by a "HAVING" clause instead of "WHERE"). The relevant portion (bottommost line) boils down to selecting for an indexed aggregate that represents a time in string format. My search criteria intentionally filters out dates that do not conform to the concatenation method used (excludes Mon YYYY and DD Mon YYYY dates). I've been trying to incorporate a "CASE" condition, but I'm not sure if/how I can fit it into the existing query.

**Simplification of the problem**

I need to modify the following query:

```
SELECT e.biomaterial_id, string_agg(e.value, ' | ') AS evalue_list
FROM biomaterialprop e
GROUP BY e.biomaterial_id;
```

Which produces:

```
 biomaterial_id |                  evalue_list                   
----------------+------------------------------------------------
              8 | NULL | Feb 2002 | Canada | T2
              4 | NULL | 03 Mar 2008 | Hainan, China | T2
              5 | nasal swab | Oct 2010 | Fujian, China | T1
             11 | nasal swab | 10 Apr 2014 | Nebraska, USA | T1
              3 | lung tissue | 01 Jan 2005 | Nebraska, USA | T2
             10 | lung tissue | 2005 | USA | T2
              9 | serum | 2001 | Ohio, USA | T1
              6 | serum | 2000 | Utah, USA | T1
              2 | serum | 01 Jan 2005 | Iowa, USA | T1
              7 | NULL | 02 Aug 1998 | Alberta, Canada | T2
```

I can select date fields via indexing with (array_agg(e.value))[3]. Next I need to modify the date strings and insert them into separate output column/s. I think it should look something like this (not currently working):

```
SELECT e.biomaterial_id, string_agg(e.value, ' | ') AS evalue_list,
  CASE char_length((array_agg(e.value))[3])
    WHEN 11 
    THEN to_date((array_agg(e.value))[3], 'DD Mon YYYY')
    WHEN 8 
    THEN to_date('01 ' || (array_agg(e.value))[3], 'DD Mon YYYY')
    ELSE to_date('01 Jan ' || (array_agg(e.value))[3], 'DD Mon YYYY')
  END
  AS date1
  CASE char_length((array_agg(e.value))[3])
    WHEN 11 
    THEN to_date((array_agg(e.value))[3], 'DD Mon YYYY')
    WHEN 8 
    THEN last_day(to_date('01 ' || (array_agg(e.value))[3], 'DD Mon YYYY'))
    ELSE to_date('31 Dec ' || (array_agg(e.value))[3], 'DD Mon YYYY')
  END
  AS date2
FROM biomaterialprop e
GROUP BY e.biomaterial_id, date1, date2;
```

I'm attempting to reproduce the query structure of answers from this stack post:
[IF-THEN-ELSE statements in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029842/if-then-else-statements-in-postgresql)

**Edit1** - It's been multiple months and I'd like to think I'm at least slightly more competent with SQL. That said, I really am not satisfied with this old solution. Any alternative suggestions or solutions would be helpful.

Demonstration of table containing time information:

```
specimen_collection_date 
--------------------------
 01-Nov-2013
 2013
 2012
 04-Jul-2013
 16-Jan-2011
 Jan-2011
 2001
 Nov-2005
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer for simplified problem**

Code:

```
create or replace function last_day(date) returns date as 'select 
cast(date_trunc(''month'', $1) + ''1 month''::interval as date) - 1' 
language sql;

SET search_path = chado;
SELECT specimen_collection_date,
  CASE
    WHEN char_length(specimen_collection_date) = 11
    THEN to_date(specimen_collection_date, 'DD Mon YYYY')
    WHEN char_length(specimen_collection_date) = 8 
    THEN to_date('01 ' || specimen_collection_date, 'DD Mon YYYY')
    ELSE to_date('01 Jan ' || specimen_collection_date, 'DD Mon YYYY')
  END
  AS date1,
  CASE
    WHEN char_length(specimen_collection_date) = 11 
    THEN to_date(specimen_collection_date, 'DD Mon YYYY')
    WHEN char_length(specimen_collection_date) = 8 
    THEN last_day(to_date('01 ' || specimen_collection_date, 'DD Mon YYYY'))
    ELSE to_date('31 Dec ' || specimen_collection_date, 'DD Mon YYYY')
  END
  AS date2
FROM prrsv_search_mv WHERE specimen_collection_date != '';
```

Output:

```
 specimen_collection_date |   date1    |   date2    
--------------------------+------------+------------
 01-Nov-2013              | 2013-11-01 | 2013-11-01
 2013                     | 2013-01-01 | 2013-12-31
 2012                     | 2012-01-01 | 2012-12-31
 04-Jul-2013              | 2013-07-04 | 2013-07-04
 16-Jan-2011              | 2011-01-16 | 2011-01-16
 Jan-2011                 | 2011-01-01 | 2011-01-31
 2001                     | 2001-01-01 | 2001-12-31
 Nov-2005                 | 2005-11-01 | 2005-11-30
```

Because PostgreSQL doesn't have a last_day function, it has to be custom made (source: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/Pine.LNX.4.44.0309021522180.17073-100000%40kix.fsv.cvut.cz).

Edit1 - Updated current answer to match most recent question edit.